# Non persistent superclass with persistent subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, jdbc, persistence

What happens when I persist this subclass?
Are the variables a and b available when I'd query the database for the Subclass object? How can I persist a and b?

```
public Superclass {

    private int a;
    private Obj b;

    // ... 
}

@Entity
public Subclass extends Superclass{
    @id int x;

    public Subclass(int a, Obj b, int x){
        super(a, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` will not be persisted.

From https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html

> Non-Entity Superclasses
>
> Entities may have non-entity superclasses, and these superclasses can
>   be either abstract or concrete. The state of non-entity superclasses
>   is nonpersistent, and any state inherited from the non-entity
>   superclass by an entity class is nonpersistent. Non-entity
>   superclasses may not be used in EntityManager or Query operations. Any
>   mapping or relationship annotations in non-entity superclasses are
>   ignored.

Comment: Follow the link in my answer and look at the Mapped Superclasses section.

Comment: I'm not interested in persisting the super class though, surely there would be another way? Overriding the variables a and b perhaps?

Comment: You could do that.  ``@MappedSuperclass`` might be what you want if you can modify ``Superclass``

Comment: That was indeed the thing I was looking for, thanks! :)